# PeopleSoft IntegrationGateway errors when consuming external REST service

Tags: openssl, weblogic, handshake, peoplesoft, handshaking

We are using PT8.53 with weblogic 10.3.6. When our process tries to consume an external REST service, the Integration Gateway error'ed out on

```
<Alert received from peer, notifying peer we received it: com.certicom.tls.record.alert.Alert@34680637>
<CLOSE_NOTIFY received from peer, closing connection: >
```

We are using a SUSE 11 VM, with openssl 0.9.8j installed. 
The 3rd party is using TLS1.2.

From the log, it seems that both party negotiated to use SSLv3, but somehow it still error'ed out.

My wild guess (I am not good at the SSL/TLS part), is that the openssl that weblogic uses is not compatible with the 3rd party's SSL/TLS, thus the 3rd party disconnected us.

My question to you all is:
1. How does Weblogic uses (if it uses) openssl? Is it compiled in there? Or it just calls a library when it tries to handshake with 3rd party?
2. If it's calling a library, how can I redirect it to a newer version of openssl? (We can install the latest openssl to a different location, not the default one).

I can't attached image. But I have a dumpcap log, which I can see the encrypted alert in there.